# How to create the animation in responsive design for my case?

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I have a weird bug on chrome that I need you guys help.

I need to have a responsive design for my app.'

The '`item`' width will change based on browser's width. The width will change accordingly when chrome first load the page. However, after I click the '`item`' and run the animation, the '`item`' width will not change anymore even though I resize my browser. I feel like it's animation issue on chrome. It works fine in FF but not Chrome. Anyone have any good suggestion? Thanks a lot!

http://jsfiddle.net/7kvX2/3/

html

```
 <div id="wrapper">
     <div class='item'>test 1</div>
     <div class='item'>test 2</div>
     <div class='item'>test 3</div>
 </div>
```

css

```
.item{
    display:inline-block;
    background-color:yellow;
}

.open{
    -webkit-animation: openMenu 1s;
    animation:openMenu 1s;
}

.close{
    -webkit-animation: closeMenu 1s;
    animation:closeMenu 1s;
}

@media (min-width: 800px) and (max-width: 1000px) {
    .item{
        width:105px;
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes openMenu{
        from {width: 105px;}
        to   {width: 170px;}
    }

    @keyframes openMenu{
        from {width: 105px;}
        to   {width: 170px;}
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes closeMenu{
        from {width: 170px;}
        to   {width: 105px;}
    }
    @keyframes closeMenu{
        from {width: 170px;}
        to   {width: 105px;}
    }
}


@media (min-width: 400px) and (max-width: 800px) {
    .item{
        width:75px;
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes openMenu{
        from {width: 75px;}
        to   {width: 100px;}
    }

    @keyframes openMenu{
        from {width: 75px;}
        to   {width: 100px;}
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes closeMenu{
        from {width: 100px;}
        to   {width: 75px;}
    }
    @keyframes closeMenu{
        from {width: 100px;}
        to   {width: 75px;}
    }
}
```

js

```
$('.item').click(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass('open')){
        $(this).addClass('close').removeClass('open');

    }else{
        $(this).addClass('open').removeClass('close');
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7kvX2/4/

your breakpoints were a little off and only worked if you fell exactly in between.

i removed the upper constraint on the first media query:

```
@media (min-width: 800px){
```

and made the lower constraint smaller and set the second parameter to 799 on the second media query:

```
@media (min-width: 100px) and (max-width: 799px) {
```